# What should be return type in interface method

Tags: java

I have two classes. `Status1` and `Status2`

these two status has one variable common:

```
protected A a;
```

and one which isnt common:

```
class Status1 {
    protected A a;
    protected ListStatus1.B version;
}
```

`B` is `static class` inside of `Status1` class

```
class Status2 {
    protected A a;
    protected Status2.C version;
}
```

`C` is `static class` inside of `Status2` class

so now I want to create interface `Status`

here I can add `variable A`. Now I need to add method `getVersion` which should return static class inside of `Status1 / Status2`

```
protected abstract ?? getVersion();
```

but I dont know what `return type` should be there

I try to add to this interface static class and this class return but with no succes

Answer (score 2):

The "right way" is to let the two static classes B and C implement a common empty `interface` , let's call is "Versioned"

```
public interface Versioned{}

static class B implements Versioned{
...
}
static class C implements Versioned{
...
}
```

After that, you can write:

```
 protected abstract Versioned getVersion();
```

and your method will be allowed to return either B or C.

Answer (score 1):

I think `Object` should do the trick!

however, while accessing any fields of the object you might face problems. Thus, I suggest you to have an interface `Version` which is implemented by the inner classes of both the statuses.

Hope this helps,

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If the difference between `Status1.B` and `Status2.C` is essential for your object model, you can make `Status` generic:

```
public interface Status<V> {
    public V getVersion();
}

public class Status1 implements Status<Status1.B> {
    public Status1.B getVersion() { ... }
    ...
}
```

Otherwise you can introduce an interface for both version classes, as suggested by other answers.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create an interface (let's call it `IVersion`) and make both version classes implement that interface. The `getVersion()` method can then return this interface:

```
protected abstract IVersion getVersion();
```